# How can you remove duplicate items from an array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have an array like this:

```
$names = array('John Doe','Marc','Rudolph', 'John Doe','Steve', 'Marc');
```

How can i remove the duplicate names with PHP?

The new array must be:

```
$names = array('John Doe','Marc','Rudolph','Steve');
```

What is already the function to do this.?

Answer (score 3):

Always check the php.net manual first.

```
$names = array('John Doe','Marc','Rudolph', 'John Doe','Steve', 'Marc');
$names = array_unique($names);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_unique()`:

```
$myArray = array(....);
$uniqueArray = array_unique( $myArray );
```

See docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_unique` But please note that this would `not work` for `case sensitive array` such as

```
 $names = array('John Doe','Marc','Rudolph','John doe','Steve','Marc');
                      ^-- Capital                 ^--Small
```

If you run

```
var_dump(array_unique($names));
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'John Doe' (length=8)
  1 => string 'Marc' (length=4)
  2 => string 'Rudolph' (length=7)
  3 => string 'John doe' (length=8)
  4 => string 'Steve' (length=5
```

Solution Convert everything to the same case before you check if it  unique

```
var_dump(arrayUnique($names));
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'John Doe' (length=8)
  1 => string 'Marc' (length=4)
  2 => string 'Rudolph' (length=7)
  4 => string 'Steve' (length=5)
```

Function Used

```
function arrayUnique($array) {
    return array_intersect_key($array, array_unique(array_map("strtolower", $array)));
}
```